# Is there something like an auto line-height?

Tags: css

I have a box in CSS with fixed dimensions, enough to fit any of my texts. 
I don't want white space between the end of the text and the bottom box border. How can I fit them into the boxes?  Something like expanding the line-height to fit.

Comment: This is a div with padding:5px; I want all the text 'expanded' to 5px to the border. Some text fit okay and others need two lines to reach the border padding

Comment: I see it also depends on the browser. Safari makes fonts smaller than Firefox, so it has more room to fill. (using em unit)

Comment: I think about getting string length from server and adjust line-height accordingly. Depending on type font'iiiiii' could use less room than 'aaaaaa'  but statistically there's no much difference in real text. JS does the job to measure text length but I want to avoid it here.

Comment: Why do you give precisions **outside** your question, like within comments ? According to : http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/line-height, there is no auto line-height. Last thing, can you provide your code ? What do you have so far ?

Answer (score 25):

```
line-height: normal;
```

Is correct.

Comment: `normal` is the default value, this shouldn't have any effect.

Comment: No, it's incorrect. `line-height:normal;` is relative to the font-size, not to the height of the surrounding element. Additionally the specific relation of `normal` to `font-size` differs from browser to browser.

Comment: Although I see your points, this "fixes" a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Try `vertical-align:bottom`.

If that doesn't work, you can try `line-height: 1em`

If that still doesn't do what you want, you'll have to clarify further what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Vertical align just moves the problem of the space from bottom to top. I think OP wants the line-height to adjust automatically so the vertical spacing is equal everywhere.

Comment: Also you have to do `display:table-cell` for vertical align to work on non table cell or image elements.

Comment: @sachleen Only if the box in question is smaller than the computed line height. By default the box will be vertically aligned to the baseline, which is slightly above the bottom line. And `display:table-cell` will vertically align the *contents* of the box, not the box itself.

Comment: I dunno, the question isn't very clear, but I was under the impression that "box" meant an html element with a border and text inside, not like an image inline with text that (the image) needs to be centered vertically.

Comment: The box has a fixed position.

Comment: @Kolink The best approach I could get was to vertical-align:middle using display:table.  Is there a vertical property like text-align:justify ?
I don't get how line-height: 1em would be useful.

Answer (score -5):

Sorry, but it's that possible only with JavaScript.

Comment: this is not possible with just javascript